# unable to cast type of Exam_Mapper to type of IMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

I'm doing a project in **ASP.NET Web Application.**  I can not cast an Object to Interface.  This is my code :

```
str2 = myXmlTextReader.ReadInnerXml();  
Type myTypeObj = testAssembly.GetType(str2);  
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myTypeObj);  
Imapper EM = (Imapper)obj;
```

In Windows Forms Application, I don't have any problem.  also the below code returns null value:

```
Imapper EM = obj as Imapper;
```

Comment: Maybe the type `myTypeObj` just don't implement `Imapper`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Exam_Mapper` type needs to implement `IMapper` in order for the code to work.  It apparently does not.  Either that or you have two types, `IMapper` and `Imapper` (you use both names in your question; possible typo), and you're confusing the two.

**Update** try this simple example, and see if it works:

```
interface ITest { }
class Test : ITest { }
//in a method
Object obj = new Test();
ITest test = (ITest)obj;
```

Now compare to your situation.  What's the difference?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but in my project Exam_Mapper implements Imapper and Imapper in all of project is Imapper no IMapper.

Comment: Step through with a debugger and see where your code isn't doing what you expect.  E.g. is myTypeObj getting your type?  Is obj an instance or null?

Comment: yes.myTypeObj gets the type and obj is an instance.but when I use   Imapper EM = (Imapper)obj;this error appears ,"unable to cast obj to Imapper" and when I use "Imapper EM = obj as Imapper;" EM returns null value.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  See the example I put up, try stepping through that, compare to your classes, and see if you can find the problem.  Without your complete code or more info, we can't do any more.

Comment: It's OK.You used a specific class but I must get the class name of the input.actually class name is an argument.